# What is the most efficient method to synchronize my database and the data received from an API?

Tags: django, database, sqlite, synchronization, pocket

I'm storing user's data and articles using the **Pocket API** into a SQLite Database using Django Framework. How can I efficiently maintain consistency between the database and the data received from the API? I'm planning to update the database once every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple with [chron jobs](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). If you already have a model with logic to fetch data from the Pocket API and parse it, it's as simple as:

```
class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 120 # every 2 hours

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        data = fetch_your_data()
        save_data(data)
```

If you don't have the parsing logic yet, I'd suggest [Django Rest Framework serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). Using the serializers is simple and saving the data shrinks down to:

```
def save_data(json_data):
    serializer = YourPocketDataSerializer(json_data)
    serializer.save()
```